# Checking if value is in database seems doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write a function which is checking if a specific value is in the firebase database and then do something when it is and do something else when it isn't. But I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: db._checkNotDeleted is not a function` error. I don't know why.

js:

```
    const onBuyHandler = (event) => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    ref(`users/${user.uid}/items/kitchen/${props.item.name}`).once(
        'value',
        (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
            } else {
                set(
                    ref(
                        db,
                        `users/${user.uid}/items/kitchen/${props.item.name}`
                    ),
                    {
                        name: props.item.name,
                        amount: 1,
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First parameter in `ref()` must be database instance.

```
const db = getDatabase();
ref(db, `users/${user.uid}/items/kitchen/${props.item.name}`)....
// ^^^ add db here
```

Comment: now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , firebase_database__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.ref)(...).once is not a function`